# pgfmathsetmacro issue in foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmath

I am trying to use \pgfmathsetmacro inside a foreach loop to connect nodes which are adjacent and named according to position as follows:

```
\foreach \src in {0,...,\T}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\dest}{\src+1};
    \path (n-\src-1) edge[<-] (n-\dest-1);
};
```

This however leads to the following error during compilation:

```
./nn.tex:54: Package pgf Error: No shape named n-1 is known. [    }]
./nn.tex:54: Package pgf Error: No shape named n-2 is known. [    }]
./nn.tex:54: Package pgf Error: No shape named n-3 is known. [    }]
./nn.tex:54: Package pgf Error: No shape named n-4 is known. [    }]
```

which makes it seem as though the \dest value is not available. How do I get around this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After the definition via `\pgfmathsetmacro`, the macro `\dest` contains a real number (`1.0`, `2.0`, ...), but very likely you need an integer.
This can be achieved by using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro` to cut the decimal fraction part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path
    \foreach \src in {0, ..., 4} {
      (\src, 0) node[circle, draw] (n-\src-1) {}
    }
  ;

  \foreach \src in {0, ..., 3} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\dest}{\src+1};
    \path (n-\src-1) edge[<-] (n-\dest-1);
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively an integer addition can be used, e.g. via eTeX's `\numexpr`:

```
\edef\dest{\the\numexpr(\src)+1}
```

Another method uses the `evaluate` key (instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro`) and the `int` function (to truncate your addition):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path
    \foreach \src in {0, ..., 4} {
      (\src, 0) node[circle, draw] (n-\src-1) {}
    }
  ;

  \foreach \src [evaluate=\src as \dest using int(\src + 1)]
  in {0, ..., 3} {
    \path (n-\src-1) edge[<-] (n-\dest-1);
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Another possibility would be to run over `\dest` and use the `remember` method of TikZ's `\foreach`, as in `\foreach \dest [remember=\dest as \src (initially 0)] in {1,...,4} {…}`.